# background images cross fading

Tags: android

I have an application which have multiple backgrounds.   I would like to cross-fade these backgrounds at a fixed time interval having one background fading out while slowly showing another (kind of like a slideshow).   I know how to use the cross-fading effect in xml but the problem is it won't show another image until the active image is totally fading out.   I want the transitions to overlap.  Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/03/07/android-bits-and-pieces-image-cross-fading.html

Answer (score 0):

see the below link,which solved my problem(cross-fade effect when changing backgrounds of a view):

[Crossfading using TransitionDrawable not working on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591384/crossfading-using-transitiondrawable-not-working-on-android)