# How to fix - error: '0f' is incompatible with attribute alpha (attr) float. error: failed linking file resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Actually I am trying to fade out one image and bring another one as a type of animation

```
public void fade(View view){

    ImageView harsh = findViewById(R.id.harshView);
    harsh.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    ImageView diksha= findViewById(R.id.dikshaView);
    diksha.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to replace an image, this can be easily done by `transistionDrawables` check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29460979/9263083

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Error . I realized that the error "0f" doesn't refer to the code that you have written in the MainActivity.java ,,, however it refers to the activity_main.xml>select the picture you are trying to fade in/out>Attributes>alpha ... in this alpha: the input doesn't require "f" after the number , remove the "f" and the error disappears ,the "f" which stands for float is only expected in the MainActivity.java code .

Answer (score 0):

> '0f' is incompatible with attribute alpha (attr) float. error: failed linking file resources

The error isn't from your code but from your `xml animation file`. Try checking for the error either in `res/anim` or `res/animator`

> Actually I am trying to fade out one image and bring another one as a type of animation

Your code is just slightly need to modified to make it work. You just need to set the second image alpha to 0. Something like this:

```
public void fade(View view) {
    ImageView harsh = findViewById(R.id.harshView);
    harsh.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    ImageView diksha= findViewById(R.id.dikshaView);
    diksha.setAlpha(0f);
    diksha.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

Comment: This can be also caused by setting  android:alpha="0f" in your view in the XML file

Comment: @Priyanthi Yeah, this was my case. You should use `android:alpha="0"` instead.